# Logic Apps Variables

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am new to Logic Apps and trying to get a good understanding of it by getting hands on and reading. I have created a few apps now and it is making more sense each time. The problem i am having is that i can create a new Dynamics record in one action, retrieve the primary key it generated in another action. But how do i use this primary value in another action to create a related record in another action. There doesn't seem to be away to store or assign variables or modify parameters on the fly?

Comment: Are you not able to consume output of previous action (which returns primary key) in next action? Ideally output of all the actions must be available to be consumed in any further actions. There is also a 'compose' action which you can use. Also there is a logic app definition language which can be used to perform various functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/definition-language Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't notice this. Clicking the show more displayed the primary key.

Answer (score 3):

Variables for Logic Apps have now been released, as of 24th March 2017. However they only currently support integers and floats, and you can only initialize or increment them.  Support for string variables, and modifying them after initialization will be coming soon. You can create them via the new Variable action.

Answer (score 3):

variables are now supported in logic app, they are available in actions, first you need to initialize your variable(currently supported types are Boolean, Integer, String, Float, object, Array) and perform the desired actions on them and also modify them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "type": "Compose" in an action to set a variable eg:

```
"IsMissing": {
  "type": "Compose",
    "inputs": {
      "what": "Something is missing"
    },
    "runAfter": {}
  }
}
```

then use body('IsMissing') to use this variable.

Comment: Brilliant, i will try this!

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that your logic app action for creating Dynamics Record is "CreateRecord". And it produces an output like this

```
{
    "primarykey" : "<guid>"
}
```

You can access the output of this action like this

```
@body('CreateRecord').primarykey
```

OR

```
@body('CreateRecord')['primarykey']
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not currently supported in Logic Apps.